# "require" doesn't work where "use" works

Tags: perl, require, perl-module, overwrite

The `My_Module`-module (used in this package) `use`s [Signals::XSIG](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Signals%3a%3aXSIG) and sets `$XSIG{'WINCH'}[1] = sub { ... };`

```
use warnings;
use 5.014;
package Auto_sid;
use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw(something);

use My_Module;

no warnings qw(redefine);

sub My_Module::list_to_big {
    my ( @arguments ) = @_;
    require Signals::XSIG;
    Signals::XSIG->import(%Signals::XSIG::XSIG);
    @{$Signals::XSIG::XSIG{'WINCH'}} = ();
    no Signals::XSIG;
    # ...
    # do something that My_Module normaly doesn't do and
    # which doesn't work when modified $SIG{'WINCH'}
    # ...
}
```

When I use this I get a lot of error-messages like:

```
"NUM63" is not exported by the Signals::XSIG module
"ARRAY(0xc23180)" is not exported by the Signals::XSIG module
"TRAP" is not exported by the Signals::XSIG module
"ARRAY(0xc119c8)" is not exported by the Signals::XSIG module
...
```

When I use `use` instead of `require` it works fine.
Why does this not work with `require`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you do this:

```
Signals::XSIG->import(%Signals::XSIG::XSIG);
```

you're passing the *contents* of that hash to the import routine. As `NUM63` and `TRAP` are signal names, and they are not valid exports for Signals::XSIG, you're getting those errors.

You need to do this:

```
Signals::XSIG->import('%XSIG');
```

Because it recognizes `Exporter` recognizes the string `'%XSIG'` as one of the things it *does* export.

Answer (score 3):

```
use Signals::XSIG qw( %XSIG );
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   require Signals::XSIG;
   Signals::XSIG->import(qw( %XSIG ));
}
```

instead of

```
# Passes the string '%XSIG'
Signals::XSIG->import(qw( %XSIG ));
```

you do

```
# Passes the contents of %Signals::XSIG::XSIG
Signals::XSIG->import(%Signals::XSIG::XSIG);
```

`import` is complaining about all the incorrect values you passed to it.

(You also got rid of the `BEGIN`, but that's unrelated to the errors you are currently getting.)